# How to auto include files with php not OOP?

Tags: php, include, include-path, require-once

I have different mods such as  **users, statistics** and etc. If I click over users I get information about users, if I click statistics I get user statistics and so on. But I want to do that automatically with php (not OOP) - auto include and call files (for example **users.php, statistics.php** and others) from *mods* folder. I know php OOP has autoload class function. But I don't know PHP Object Oriented. How can I do that with PHP without OOP?
I want links to be like that:

```
<a href='index.php?mod=users'>User list</a> <a href='index.php?mod=statistics'>Statistics</a>
```

Comment: you want to auto include all files from mods folder or du you want to auto include users.php from folder mods if $_GET["mod"] is users?

Comment: @micha I want to auto include users.php from folder mods if $_GET["mod"] is users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET["mod"]) && file_exists("mods/" . preg_replace("/[^\w\d]+/", "", $_GET["mod"]) . ".php")) {
    include "mods/" . preg_replace("/[^\w\d]+/", "", $_GET["mod"]) . ".php"; // or: require("mods/" . preg_replace("/[^\w\d]+/", "", $_GET["mod"]) . ".php");
}
```

Comment: You need to sanitise the input. What if someone crafted a URL where $_GET['mod'] was ../../../../../../../etc/passwd or similar? Also the difference between include and require is more than just one is more modern than the other.

Comment: @liquorvicar how can I sanitize input?

Comment: @EmilAzizov I sanitize the input directly after liquorvicar reminded me that I should do that.

Comment: @micha I would recommend a "whitelist" style approach to sanitisation. For example, the OP is looking to include files of the form mods/NAME.php. Thus if his php includes only ever include letters and underscores, I would remove all characters except these.

Comment: If you think it is better, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch`/`case` or some system of mod sanitation.

```
// BASE_PATH is some previously defined application path constant

// fetch $mod from $_GET, and if set strtolower() it

switch($mod){
    case 'user':
    case 'admin':
    case 'statistics':
        $path = realpath(BASE_PATH . "/mods/{$mod}.php");
        if(false === $path || !is_file($path)){
            // error, 404?
        }
        require $path;
        break;
    default:
        // invalid mod, 404?
        break;
}

// and so forth
```